handle_event receives form updates with duplicate parameters
I am trying to build a simple search screen using Phoenix/LiveView.
The screen is very simple: search bar + filters on the right-hand side. The filters are just multiple choice checkboxes.
A checkbox is implemented like this:
defp multi_select(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div class="...">
      <%= for option <- @options do %>
        <label class="...">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={"#{input_name(@form, @field.field)}[]"}
            value={option}
            checked={option in @field.value}
            class="..."
          />
          <span class="...">{option}</span>
        </label>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    """
  end

When I select/deselect the checkbox, being part of the form, handle_event is called where I push_patch like this:
def handle_event("apply_filters", %{"search_form" => search_form}, socket) do
    # Convert array parameters to comma-separated strings
    formatted_params =
      search_form
      |> Map.take(["query", "platforms"])
      |> Map.update("platforms", "", fn platforms ->
        platforms |> List.wrap() |> Enum.uniq() |> Enum.join(",")
      end)

    {:noreply, push_patch(socket, to: ~p"/search?#{formatted_params}")}
  end

Then, I parse the URL in handle_params:
def handle_params(params, _uri, socket) do
    attrs = Map.take(params, ["query", "platforms"])

    attrs =
      attrs
      |> Map.update("platforms", [], &string_to_list/1)

    search_form = SearchForm.changeset(%SearchForm{}, attrs)

    socket =
      socket
      |> assign(:products, search_products(search_form))
      |> assign(:search_form, to_form(search_form))

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  defp string_to_list(""), do: []
  defp string_to_list(nil), do: []

  defp string_to_list(string) when is_binary(string) do
    string
    |> String.split(",", trim: true)
    |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Enum.reject(&(&1 == ""))
  end

  defp string_to_list(list) when is_list(list), do: list

It all works fine, as long as I enable checkboxes: the params are added to URL, and filtering happens and the UI is correct. But when I start unchecking checkboxes, the UI is updated, but the URL still contains all the unchecked options. It comes from how weirdly the params are received in the handle_event. Here's the flow:

I enter the screen, the url is http://localhost:4000/search?query=test
I enable a checkbox, the params of handle_event are
"search_form" => %{"_unused_query" => "", "platforms" => ["web"], "query" => "test"}

the url becomes: http://localhost:4000/search?platforms=web&query=test

I enable another checkbox. The params:
"search_form" => %{"_unused_query" => "", "platforms" => ["web", "web", "mobile"], "query" => "test"}

Already here I don't understand why web is present twice there. But because I remove duplicates, the URL seems fine so far:
http://localhost:4000/search?platforms=web%2Cmobile&query=test

And now, when I disable one of the checkboxes (web), things get really bad. The params are:
"search_form" => %{"_unused_query" => "", "platforms" => ["web", "mobile", "mobile"], "query" => "test"}

The UI looks good, but the URL looks like this:
http://localhost:4000/search?platforms=web%2Cmobile&query=test
event though I would expect that web should not be there.
If I enable/disable checkboxes a bit more, the handle_event params become even worse. And because the disabled options are still present in the url, this breaks the filtering logic.
I tried debugging and re-formatting params, but I guess the problem lies in how I work with the form, and I don't see where I am wrong.
Also, I checked this article: https://fly.io/phoenix-files/persistent-forms-with-your-url-on-liveview/
It works for me the same as long as I have only query - the string param. But when I have filters, which are lists, the problems start to happen.
Any advice is welcome.

The diff is coming. One should calculate the diff between the new value(["web", "mobile", "mobile"]) and the obsoleted one (["web", "web", "mobile"]) to get to what’s changed. Here we can see mobile has been enabled and web has been disabled.
